# Passing params from android to Web Api

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api

I could make it work like this but there gotto be a better way. Any suggestion?

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("token", session.getAccessToken()));

HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(URL);
try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {}
httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

**Web Api**

```
[AcceptVerbs("GET", "POST")]
public IHttpActionResult FBToken()
{
    string token = ((HttpContextWrapper)Request.Properties["MS_HttpContext"]).Request.Params["token"];

    //some code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public IHttpActionResult FBToken(TokenRequest request)
{
        //some code that uses request.Token
}

public class TokenRequest
{
    public string Token { get; set; }
}
```

UPDATE

Oops, sorry thought I typed more. Anyways, here is the explanation. `UrlEncodedFormEntity` sets the content type of the request message to application/x-www-form-urlencoded. ASP.NET Web API has built-in media type formatter for de-serializing such content. By using a complex type (`TokenRequest` class), we ask Web API to bind the request body to this type and we get the token out using the `Token` property. This is better because we are not taking dependency on ASP.NET anywhere. This is easier to unit test and host-agnostic.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.